# How to call a partial outside of Admin scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form for :

```
  <%= form_tag({controller: 'site_members', action: 'import' }, :class => 'csv_import_form', :multipart => true) do %>
```

But because I'm calling this partial inside of ActiveAdmin's `/admin` scope, it's prepending my action with `admin` :

```
No route matches {:controller=>"admin/site_members", :action=>"import"}
```

Instead of the working version which would be the above error without the `admin`.

How do I call the root controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to prepend the path with a slash to stop it from adding the admin scope:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: '/site_members', action: 'import' }, :class => 'csv_import_form', :multipart => true) do %>
```

But I would instead recommend you create a proper route for this method and use that.

routes.rb

```
post 'site_members' => 'site_member#import'

<%= form_tag(site_members_url, :class => 'csv_import_form', :multipart => true) do %>
```

Comment: Ah fantastic! Thats it. Thanks for the quick answer